# Animation not work on Ellipse

Tags: xaml, storyboard, uwp, visualstatemanager

I am trying to animate an ellipse which will grow bigger on State Changes.
I can't seem to get the transition working on Width and Height.

Note that if I change the `TargetProperty` to `(FrameworkElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)`, the transition applies.

Here's the ControlTemplate I used:

```
<Border>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ControlStates">
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition x:Name="ClosedToOpened" 
                                      From="Closed" To="Opened"
                                      GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" Storyboard.TargetName="Bubble">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="10" EasingFunction="{StaticResource EaseOutQuintic}" />
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="50" EasingFunction="{StaticResource EaseOutQuintic}" />
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" Storyboard.TargetName="Bubble">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="10" EasingFunction="{StaticResource EaseOutQuintic}" />
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="50" EasingFunction="{StaticResource EaseOutQuintic}" />
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualTransition>
                <VisualTransition x:Name="OpenedToClosed" 
                                      From="Opened" To="Closed"
                                      GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" Storyboard.TargetName="Bubble">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="50" EasingFunction="{StaticResource EaseOutQuintic}" />
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="10" EasingFunction="{StaticResource EaseOutQuintic}" />
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" Storyboard.TargetName="Bubble">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="50" EasingFunction="{StaticResource EaseOutQuintic}" />
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="10" EasingFunction="{StaticResource EaseOutQuintic}" />
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualTransition>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualStateGroup.States>
                <VisualState x:Name="Opened">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Bubble" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" Duration="0" To="50" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Bubble" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" Duration="0" To="50" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Closed">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Bubble" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" Duration="0" To="10" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Bubble" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" Duration="0" To="10" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup.States>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Ellipse x:Name="Bubble" Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Black" />
</Border>
```

How do I get the transition working?

(I tried ScaleX/Y but it gives a pixel-Ly result when animating)

Comment: You should definitely be doing rendertransform/scale animation like you were, as to the resulting rendering I might assume it would be related to [this type of issue](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/54770/why-would-i-get-aliasing-on-a-vector-like-this)

Comment: @ChrisW. The result is not like the question you linked to. It is more like directly converted to a bitmap image then just scaling it causing a mosaic effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your animation is a dependent animation, by default, the animation system won't run a dependent animation. To enable your animation, you need set the `EnableDependentAnimation` property of the animation object to `True`.

In WinRT, there are two kinds of animations: [Dependent and independent animations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt187354.aspx#dependent).

> An animation is **independent** if it has any of these characteristics:
>
> - The **Duration** of the animation is 0 seconds (see Caution)
> - The animation targets **UIElement.Opacity**
> - The animation targets a sub-property value of these UIElement properties: **RenderTransform**, **Projection**, **Clip**
> - The animation targets **Canvas.Left** or **Canvas.Top**
> - The animation targets a **Brush** value and uses a **SolidColorBrush**, animating its **Color**
> - The animation is an **ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames**
>
> If your animation doesn't meet these criteria, it's probably a **dependent** animation.

To make your transition working, you can change your code like following:

```
<Border>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ControlStates">
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition x:Name="ClosedToOpened"
                                  From="Closed"
                                  GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5"
                                  To="Opened">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames EnableDependentAnimation="True" Storyboard.TargetName="Bubble" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource EaseOutQuintic}" KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="10" />
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource EaseOutQuintic}" KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="50" />
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames EnableDependentAnimation="True" Storyboard.TargetName="Bubble" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource EaseOutQuintic}" KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="10" />
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource EaseOutQuintic}" KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="50" />
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualTransition>
                <VisualTransition x:Name="OpenedToClosed"
                                  From="Opened"
                                  GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5"
                                  To="Closed">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames EnableDependentAnimation="True" Storyboard.TargetName="Bubble" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource EaseOutQuintic}" KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="50" />
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource EaseOutQuintic}" KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="10" />
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames EnableDependentAnimation="True" Storyboard.TargetName="Bubble" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource EaseOutQuintic}" KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="50" />
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource EaseOutQuintic}" KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="10" />
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualTransition>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            ...
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    ...
 </Border>
```